# React Table resize buggs out when scrolled all the way to the right

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm currently working on an older version of react-table, and when I scroll all the way to the right (or just a bit) the column resize goes nuts.

As I'm showing down below, the first pic is when the table X is at 0 (scrolled to the left)
[image]

And here is scrolled to the right and the mobile ID column was resized, first it was dragged to the right and then pulled back
[image]

This seems to occur only in Mozilla Firefox, Chrome seems fine.

React table version (I could update this dependency, but I don't really know how far I can push before breaking something):

```
"react-table": "6.8.6",
```

And with that it looks like there's an older & customized version of `react-table-hoc-fixed-columns`, but since whoever did this project took the source code and changed it's really outdated and with no way of updating this right now, without breaking something.

Comment: This is probably question for maintainers of react-table. I think you should open Bug issue on their Github repo to get an answer. Also you need to create minimal solution that reproduces the bug so that others can assist.

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem; I can't think of a quick way to replicate this bug because this is a legacy project that was used/created 5-6 years ago, so there's too much on the plate for me to reproduce, and I believe this is too specific for this bug. As a result, I believe that assisting me will be extremely difficult. In any case, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so I can help anyone who is unfortunate to have this problem, the only thing that was messing with the table Headers was a random CSS attribute `position: sticky` that was making the filters messy. Nothing related to `react-table` or it's version.